# Как вывести элементы по порядку через getlist?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет !

Подскажите, как выводить элементы через CIBlockElement::GetList, что бы элементы выводились по 50 на странице, но при перезагрузке страницы выводились следущие 50 элементов

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
$page = $_SESSION["LAST_PAGE"]>0?$_SESSION["LAST_PAGE"]:1;
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_*");//IBLOCK_ID и ID обязательно должны быть указаны, см. описание arSelectFields выше
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>IntVal($yvalue), "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50, "iNumPage"=>$page), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
   $arFields = $ob->GetFields();  
   print_r($arFields);
   $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
   print_r($arProps);
}
$_SESSION["LAST_PAGE"] = $page++;
```